# Ultrasound softening

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation

Greeting

I'm a Cardio Technology specialist to be
I've an assignment which starts with, What does Ultrasound softening stands for?

I couldn't find any answer related to physics
so, I really need your help

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is a process called "softening", i.e., reduction of hardness, so I guess "ultrasound softening" is just softening using ultrasound (see, e.g.,  https://www.tctmd.com/news/ultrasound-may-prove-useful-softening-calcified-bioprosthetic-valves )